# Imaginary Numbers Case Work

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Compute the number of ordered pairs of integers $(x,y)$ with $1\le x<y\le 100$ such that $i^x+i^y$ is a real number.

So far I have found the cases in which they will work. But I am not sure how to calculate the number of pairs for each case.

The cases I found are:

$(i^x=-1$, $i^y=-1)$

$(i^x = i, i^y=-i)$

$(i^x = -i, i^y=i)$

$(i^x = 1, i^y=-1)$

$(i^x = -1, i^y=1)$

$(i^x = 1, i^y = 1)$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let $A=\{n\in\mathbb{Z}, n\textrm{ is even and }1\le n\le100\}$, $B=\{n\in\mathbb{Z}, n\equiv 1 (\textrm{mod }4) \textrm{ and }1\le n\le100\}$ and $C=\{n\in\mathbb{Z}, n\equiv 3 (\textrm{mod }4) \textrm{ and }1\le n\le100\}$

We need (1) both $x,y\in A$, or (2) $x\in B$ and $y\in C$, or (3) $x\in C$ and $y\in B$.